# Why we need more codes to redirecting from www to non-www in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, url-rewriting, asp.net-core-3.1

I was looking to find a way to redirect www to non-www and find some posts and codes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581721/redirecting-www-mywebapp-azurewebsites-net-to-https-mywebapp-azurewebsites-ne):

```
public class NonWwwRule : IRule
{
   public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
      var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
      var currentHost = req.Host;
      if (currentHost.Host.StartsWith("www."))
         {
             var newHost = new HostString(currentHost.Host.Substring(4), currentHost.Port ?? 80);
             var newUrl = men 
              StringBuilder().Append("https://").Append(newHost).Append(req.PathBase)
             .Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);
              context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString(), true);
              context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            }
     }
}
```

and use this class like:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions();
options.Rules.Add(new NonWwwRule());
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Tested and it works fine but to redirect from non-www to www just need a line of code:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToWww());
```

My question is that why redirecting from www to non-www needs a lot of code?

Is there a better way without a lot of code to handle it without accessing to web.config and IIS in .net core 3.1?

Comment: Hi motevalizadeh, in the meantime I've rewritten my question. Please see my new post searching for "Redirecting ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Web App not working". In my case the class does not work, but I think now that is related to the App Service Plan free tier (F1) that I'm using. Which plan did you use? I do agree with yoor question. Why not adding a simple method like RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToNonWww()?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft add the extension method in ASP.NET Core 5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptionsextensions.addredirecttowww?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In version 3.1 we need to add a class like you do

P.S. There is a typo in your code.

```
var newUrl = men StringBuilder()
```