# In .Net Core 5, How to redirect www to non-www URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, no-www

On a subdomain want to redirect all requests with www to non-www, because of that, using this line of code in the "Start.up", in the "Configure" method like below but it doesn't work.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToNonWww());
            ...
        }
   ...
}
```

What's wrong with my codes? I don't want to write some extra codes [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667437/why-we-need-more-codes-to-redirecting-from-www-to-non-www-in-net-core), because it seems there is a function to handle it.

Comment: I have tested the codes on my side, it works well. Since you put this codes inside the condition, I suggest you could try to put this codes outside the if condition and test it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in  **.net Core 5** put the follow code inside Strartup.cs Configure function

```
 app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToNonWwwPermanent()
            .AddRedirectToHttps()
         );
```

If you use **.net Core 6** put the code inside program.cs